# Same screen density buckets but different layout sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-density

I am testing an application in two mobiles one is ASUS ZENPHONE 5Z another one is ONEPLUS 6T,Both of the device screen densities are same and both of them have falls in **XXHDPI**  but where as the layout appears different in both the phone as shown below.

**ASUS 5Z**

[image]

**ONEPLUS 6T**

[image]

I have checked the mobile settings they are about same, so what is this all about and how do i fix it?

Comment: have you set the height in `dp` or it's `wrap_content`?

Comment: wrap_content for card dp for image padding

Comment: that might be the issue. try [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) instead of `dp` and [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) instead of `sp`. this might help.

Comment: Okay will try and update